# How does a factor order it's levels automaticly in R?

Tags: r

```
f1 <- c("a", "b", "c")

f2 <- c("x", "e", "t")

f1 <-factor(f1)

f1
#[1] a b c
#Levels: a b c


str(f1)
#Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3

f2 <-factor(f2)

f2
#[1] x e t
#Levels: e t x

str(f2)
#Factor w/ 3 levels "e","t","x": 3 1 2
```

As mentioned above, why in `f2` is `"e"` being taken as 3? Shouldn't it be 1, when it considered in alphabetical order?

Comment: `"e"` is coded as 1. You've misunderstood the `str` output.

Comment: It is ok. I understand it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set `f2` as `c("x", "e", "t")` therefore "x" which is factor `3` (from alphabetical order) is still in first position, while "e" which is in second position has really factor `1`

```
    f2 <- factor(c("x", "e", "t"))
    str(f2)
    Factor w/ 3 levels "e","t","x": 3 1 2
```

Description of `str(f2)` results:

- `f2` is of type Factor, this means the values are not to be taken as is, but are coded as factors
- `f2` has 3 levels of factor (3 different values), which are in order "e", "t", "x", so "e" is coded as factor 1, "t" is coded as factor 2 and "x" is coded as factor 3
- `f2` contains 3 coded values 3, 1, 2

To de-factorize:

- take the 1st coded value (3), and replace it by its level ("x"=factor 3),
- then the 2nd coded value (1), and replace it by its level ("e"=factor 1),

...

- then the last coded value (2), and replace it by its level ("t"=factor 2)

=> you get "x", "e", "t".

Let's add an extra value ("e" again) at the end of `f2`

```
    f2[4] <-  "e"
    str(f2)
    Factor w/ 3 levels "e","t","x": 3 1 2 1
```

You can see that a factor 1 coding for an "e" is now at the 4th position.

`f2` now represents : "x", "e", "t", "e".

Comment: as you say "e" which is in the second position, but in my example "e" is factored as "3", not (in real) "1" or "2"?

Answer (score 1):

The str(f2) shows the letters in alphabetical order, but the numbers are according the place occupied by letters in the f2 object.

if f2 is x e t

```
 Levels are e t x (in order)

 Numbers for the above letters would be: (in order)

 e = 1
 t = 2
 x = 3

 str gives number sequence according to the place occupied by the letters in     
 the original f2 object , i.e. x, e, t = 3,1,2
```

Hope this helps.